# Cross Domain Defining using require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'm learning how to use [require.js](http://requirejs.org/). I am trying to define modules like this:

```
define('presenter', ['jquery'].......
```

The problem is that my host page is on a different domain at 'http://localhost:62607/' so I get a 404 error looking for presenter there.

Presenter is actually located here: 'http://localhost:62588/scripts/app/presenter'.

So if I define presenter like:

```
define('http://localhost:62588/scripts/app/presenter', ['jquery'],
```

Everything works fine but I much prefer the more readable first version.

Is there anything that can be done to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `baseUrl` and `path` properties in the requireJS configuration for achieving this.

From the requireJS documentation:

```
requirejs.config({
  //By default load any module IDs from js/lib
  baseUrl: 'js/lib',
  //except, if the module ID starts with "app",
  //load it from the js/app directory. paths
  //config is relative to the baseUrl, and
  //never includes a ".js" extension since
  //the paths config could be for a directory.
  paths: {
    app: '../app'
  }
});
```

If you define a module called `app`, requireJS will look for it at `../app`

Comment: Thanks.  Exactly what I needed.  Just include baseUrl and remember and remove the .js.  E.g. when referencing prenter.js.